# Dictionary literals in Mako expressions

Tags: mako

The following throws a syntax error, "unexpected EOF while parsing":

```
${foo({'bar':'baz'})}
```

which I guess is from the inner closing curly brace.
This works fine:

```
${foo(dict(bar='baz'))}
```

but what's the syntax for using a dictionary literal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Brian Rue on the [Mako Templates Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/mako-discuss):

This is a long-outstanding bug; just use dict(). If you need a dictionary 
with keys that aren't strings, convert a list of tuples into a dict.
e.g. instead of this:

`${foo({1: 'a', 2: 'b'})}`

do this:

`${foo(dict([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]))}`